# How has Stack Overflow implemented an custom ASP.NET Membership Provider?

Tags: discussion

Has a rough database schema for the SO users/membership ever been published? I've seen that the Data Explorer shows the following columns for a user:

1. Id
2. Reputation
3. CreationDate
4. DisplayName
5. LastAccessDate
6. WebsiteUrl
7. Location
8. AboutMe
9. Views
10. UpVotes
11. DownVotes
12. EmailHash
13. Age

OpenID and the standard ASP.NET Membership don't play so nicely together, yet SO has an excellent user-friendly sign up/in process. I'd love someone to share how the SO Membership and User tables are architected.

Notably, the DisplayName is case sensitive (i.e. 'Junto' and 'junto' are two different users) and standard ASP.NET Membership lower-cases all usernames before checking for dupes. Therefore it suggests that they have written a Custom Membership provider, especially since they have the possibility of having multiple OpenId logins tied to the one account.

Would anyone like to have a guess at the database schema? It would be interesting to see how this is done correctly.

Comment: Note that "Junto" and "Junto" can also be separate users.

Comment: I would not consider using the Membership Provider for any large or complex site, as it tries to be "all things for all people".

Comment: @John. Thanks I didn't realise that.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose I'd like to hear more!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/), the software that runs http://data.stackexchange.com.

From it you can obtain a *lot* of code that is shared with the "normal" Q&A platform, including user management/registration/login but even things like markdown parsing, routing, database structure, etc.

It was an invaluable resource for me while learning ASP.NET.

Comment: I think I just got a little over excited. Superb. Looks like the FormAuthentication ticket is issued manually. No ASP.NET Membership to be seen. IsAdmin flag on the user is the only roles type stuff. Event the table schemas are listed. You made my Friday. :-)

Comment: @Junto: I had a similar reaction when I discovered how many "general purpose" things it had that I could learn =)

Comment: @Junto to confirm : we simply ***do not use*** the membership provider; the user-identity code is bespoke

Comment: @Mark Gravell Was the reason behind the decision due to the fact that the standard ASP.NET Membership is clunky and slow, or simply that it wasn't a good fit for a multiple identity, single user account model?